# Convert a list of objects to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of JSON objects, already sorted (by time let's say). Each JSON object has `type` and `status`. For example:

```
[
    {'type': 'A', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'type': 'B', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'type': 'A', 'status': 'fail'}
]
```

I'd like to convert it to:

```
{
    'A': ['ok', 'fail'],
    'B': ['ok']
}
```

So of course it's an easy task but I'm looking for the Pythonic way doing that, so it will spare me a few lines of code

Comment: Maybe share the code you have currently written then people can give you pointers on how to make it work better or more pythonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a one-liner but you can make use of [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) or [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to achieve the desired result as:

```
data = [
    {'type': 'A', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'type': 'B', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'type': 'A', 'status': 'fail'}
]
```

Using `setdefault()`:

```
res = {}
for elt in data:
    res.setdefault(elt['type'], []).append(elt['status'])
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['ok', 'fail'], 'B': ['ok']}
```

Using `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for elt in data:
    res[elt['type']].append(elt['status'])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['ok', 'fail'], 'B': ['ok']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your new structure depends on older (already processed) keys also, I doubt you can use dictionary comprehension (which operates on per-key basis) to achieve the required final state.

I would prefer to use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) where each default key is a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict
new_data = defaultdict(list)
for item in data:
    new_data[item['type']].append(item['status'])
print(new_data)
```

which gives output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['ok', 'fail'], 'B': ['ok']})
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner with multiple list comprehensions and `sorted(set(…))` to remove the duplicate keys:

```
original = [
    {"type": "A", "status": "ok"},
    {"type": "B", "status": "ok"},
    {"type": "A", "status": "fail"},
]

result = {
    key: [x["status"] for x in original if x["type"] == key]
    for key in sorted(set([x["type"] for x in original]))
}
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['ok', 'fail'], 'B': ['ok']}
```